# Visa for transit through Oman?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, uk-citizens, oman

I'm a British Citizen traveling to India, connecting flight in Oman, do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Per Timatic, the database used by Airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa)::
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
>     international transit area of the airport and have documents
>     required for the next destination..

So if you're on a single ticket, you do **not** need a visa.

If on separate tickets, you can get a visa on arrival or an e-visa in advance.

Comment: Can get an eVisa too if you are saying longer that 24 hours https://evisa.rop.gov.om/

Comment: @SamJones Or a visa on arrival

Comment: UK gov says to get an eVisa, but guessing none of this applies to OP https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/oman/entry-requirements

Comment: @SamJones You can still get a visa on arrival no matter what GOV.UK says

Comment: @Crazydre What if I’m on separate tickets, would I absolutely need a visa?

Comment: @Qasim Officially not, but in practice check-in staff will very likely require it. If you have checked bags they have to be collected after border control, but even if you don't, if something goes wrong with your connection you could be stuck, as you're not "insured" with separate tickets, and the last thing the airline wants is having to send you back. **That said**, if your nationality can get a visa on arrival anyway, this is in practice a non-issue

Comment: @Crazydre Thanks dude! I was thinking about perhaps changing my flight (less costly).

Comment: @Qasim If you cannot get a visa on arrival or e-visa in the transit country, you should change it